# Why is the default value of DateTime variable changed after being sent as message?

Tags: c#, datetime

I am developing two applications communicating by messages. I got a problem, looked like a bug, when receiving the default value of the datetime.

I expected to receive the default value of datetime ***'1/01/0001 12:00:00 AM'*** but received ***'30/12/1899 12:00:00 AM'*** instead.

The datetime variable is a member of a struct, and the struct is passed over to COPYDATASTRUCT.

I tried to assign new DateTime(), default(DateTime) and .MinValue to it, but the result was the same. I guess that it is changed by Windows OS. Maybe the default value is different between Windows OS and C#.

This is the simple code following.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct COPYDATASTRUCT
{
    public IntPtr dwData;
    public int    cbData;
    public IntPtr lpData;
}
```

```
public struct USERMSGSTRUCT
{
    public DateTime date;
}
```

```
public static class WinMessages
{
    public const int WM_COPYDATA = 0x004A;
    public const int WM_USER     = 0x0400;
    public const int WM_APP      = 0x8000;
}
```

```
public static class UserMessages
{
    public const int UM_CONNECT = 100;
}
```

```
[DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

This is a code to send a message containing DateTime variable.

Sender.cs

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    USERMSGSTRUCT ums = new USERMSGSTRUCT();
    COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
    IntPtr targetHwnd = IntPtr.Zero;

    // Finds target Application Handle
    Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("Receiver"); // <-- Put the process name of the receiver application.
    if (pname.Length > 0)
    { targetHwnd = pname[0].MainWindowHandle; }

    // CDS Message
    cds.dwData = IntPtr.Zero;
    cds.cbData = Marshal.SizeOf(ums);

    IntPtr structPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(ums));
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(ums, structPtr, false);
    cds.lpData = structPtr;

    IntPtr iPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(cds));
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(cds, iPtr, false);

    // Prints the value of DateTime var. and sends it to the target App.
    Console.WriteLine(ums.date);    // <-- '1/01/0001 12:00:00 AM'
    SendMessage(
        targetHwnd, 
        (int)WinMessages.WM_COPYDATA, 
        new IntPtr(UserMessages.UM_CONNECT), 
        iPtr);

    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(iPtr);
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(structPtr);
}
```

Receiver.cs

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
    USERMSGSTRUCT ums;

    if ((uint)m.Msg == WinMessages.WM_COPYDATA)
    {
        cds = (COPYDATASTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(COPYDATASTRUCT));
        ums = (USERMSGSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(cds.lpData, typeof(USERMSGSTRUCT));

        switch ((uint)m.WParam) // User Message
        {
            case UserMessages.UM_CONNECT:
                Console.WriteLine(ums.date); // <-- '30/12/1899 12:00:00 AM'
                break;
            default: break;
        }
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

How can I get the default value of the DateTime variable when receiving?

Comment: Appears to be related (?): https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/3568d5b7-f275-4730-bf66-15209fb4d198/date-being-changed-from-111900-to-12311899?forum=accessdev

Comment: You're getting the default behavior of the marshaller, which tries to marshal `DateTime` as an OLE automation date/time. Those don't support values earlier than 1899-12-30. Effectively, you're getting `DateTime.FromOADate(DateTime.MinValue.ToOADate())`. I'd marshal `DateTime.Ticks` instead as a `long`. (Well, actually, I'd marshal nothing at all and use something like WCF/gRPC/named pipes/whatever for IPC rather than `WM_COPYDATA`, but that's another matter.)

Comment: Marshal.StructureToPtr() is intended to be used to interop with unmanaged code, not to serialize data.  You discovered what it does with DateTime, that is not a type that unmanaged code ever knows anything about.  The interop type for dates is an OLE date, same value that DateTime.ToOADate() returns.  Its lowest possible value is 30/12/1899.

Comment: Thanks @FrankAlvaro. It is not the answer but it could be a hint.

Comment: Oh~~ Thanks a lot  @HansPassant for your fast answers. Now It is clear. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert, too.